# How can I separate middle names/initials after fields, and should it be done before/after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, parsing, insert

I have the following table:

```
InventorLast    InventorFirst
Bram            Ernst Arne Johan
Gesing          Ernst Rudolf F.
Beranek         Ernst W.
Koch            Ernst-Christian
Bozak           Erol
Kurtas          Erozan Mehmet
Calder          Errol Jay
Binder          Erwin
Goetschi        Erwin
```

I want to seperate the middle name/initial on either the first space or - as seen in the Ernst-Christian example.

Would it be easier for me to do this after I create my table, or on insert from the source data?

The existing insert sequence is as follows:

```
insert into Inventor (PatentNo, InventorFirst, InventorLast, City, statename, country, NationalityCountry, ResidenceCountry)
select PatentNo, InventorFirstname, InventorLastname, City, statename, country, NationalityCountry, ResidenceCountry
from InventorUpdate
where InventorFirstName is not null 
and InventorLastName is not null
```

I am aware the I will have to add the InventorMiddle column.  I just need some help with 
the coding.

Thanks!

Comment: Even excluding cultural differences outside of the U.S., name parsing for American names is an almost impossible task unless you ask the user to do it for you.  Example problem Names Billy Jean Jackson Haskins. Given name: Billy Jean, Middle Name: Jackson, Family Name: Haskins.

Comment: What about last names which are legitimately multiple words? For example, inventors Édouard-Léon Scott de Martinville and Hippolyte Marié-Davy.

Comment: Companies make millions of dollars [selling software that does data scrubbing and cleansing](http://www.melissadata.com/name-parsing/index.htm). Do you think there is a simple query that will handle all cases the way that they do? I'm not trying to be a salesman, but sometimes DIY is not the way. My sister's name, no joke, is Casey Cayla-Dawn Bertrand-Resmer. I've had friends named Dennis Moseley-Williams & Heidi van der Wal. And what about Prince and Metta World Peace? You can probably get pretty close with substring and charindex/patindex, but in a lot of cases you're going to have to guess.

Comment: Are you sure that `Ernst-Christian Koch` _has_ a middle name, as opposed to just a hyphenated first name?

Comment: I agree with all of you, just wanted to get some more opinions on this so that when I tell the person I am doing this for that it is an unreasonable request I will have more examples to throw at them.  Look at someone with the last van der voort .  Where do you decide what seperates the name, and how do you do it without having to go through countless records manually

Comment: Personal experience : I had to do this kind of jobs (names splitting, address splitting) on an ugly db. Even if it's far from perfect, I used to manage correctly more than 90% of cases with regex (more sophisticated than in my answer, but anyway). The rest had to be cleaned by users. I think that 90% is not negligible anyway. The problem is : detect the 10%, of course !

Comment: The problem with 10% is that it is relative, 10% of 5,000 records would be 500 to parse out individually, 10% of 100,000 records would be 10,000.  In some cases it makes sense, specifically when the DB is smaller, or when you have someone with the patience to go through and fix records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather ugly,but...

Think you just didn't say what to do when there's just a "no space no - name"

```
select substring(InventorFirst, 0, (case when  
                 patindex('%[ -]%', InventorFirst) = 0
                 then len(InventorFirst) + 1
                 else patindex('%[ -]%', InventorFirst)
                 end)
                 ) as middleValue,
       case 
         when patindex('%[ -]%', InventorFirst) = 0
          then '' 
          else substring(InventorFirst, 
                         patindex('%[ -]%', InventorFirst)+1, 
                         len(InventorFirst))
       end as endValue 
                 from inventor
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57fa7/20